# Find the "name" of a library (-L -l switches)

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, g++, command-line-arguments

Being fairly new to C++ I have a question bascially concerning the g++ compiler and especially the inclusion of libraries. Consider the following makefile:

```
CPPFLAGS= -I libraries/boost_1_43_0-bin/include/ -I libraries/jpeg-8b-bin/include/
LDLIBS= libraries/jpeg-8b-bin/lib/libjpeg.a
# LDLIBS= -L libraries/jpeg-8b-bin/lib -llibjpeg

all: main

main: main.o
    c++ -o main main.o $(LDLIBS)

main.o: main.cpp
    c++ $(CPPFLAGS) -c main.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *.o main
```

As you can see I declared the LDLIBS variable twice. My code is compiling and working if I use the makefile above. But if I deactivate the first LDLIBS entry and active the second one I get `ld: library not found for -llibjpeg`. I assume my `libjpeg.a` is just not called `libjpeg` but bears some different name.

Is there a way to find out the name of a given "libraryfile" `libsomething.a` or `libsomething.dyn`?

---

Ok, thanks for all your answers, it is working now.
One little question remains: Is it a  convention to simply leave out "lib" or is there a standardized way to find out the name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need the `lib` part if you use the `-l` switch.

```
LDLIBS=-Llibraries/jpeg-8b-bin/lib -ljpeg
#                                    ^^^^
```

---

Whenever you write `-lxxx`, the linker will look for a library with filename `libxxx.<ext>` in all supplied library paths. This is the standard convention of `ld`, and should be true for most UNIX-based linkers.

Answer (score 3):

Typically if you use your second form of LDLIBS declaration you should drop the letters lib in -llibjpeg to get -ljpeg.

Answer (score 3):

No space between -I or -L and the path that follows, and -lxxx implies lib, so

```
-Llibraries/jpeg-8b-bin/lib -ljpeg
```

should do the trick.